# Theano conv2d and max_pool_2d

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, convolution, theano

When implementing a [convolutional neural network (CNN) in theno](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html) one comes across two variants of `conv2d` operator:

- [`theano.tensor.nnet.conv.conv2d`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/nnet/conv.html#theano.tensor.nnet.conv.conv2d)
- [`theano.tensor.signal.conv.conv2d`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/signal/conv.html#theano.tensor.signal.conv.conv2d)

And an implementation of max-pooling:

- [`theano.tensor.signal.downsample.max_pool_2d`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/signal/downsample.html#theano.tensor.signal.downsample.max_pool_2d)

My questions are:

1. What is the difference between the two implementations of `conv2d`?
2. What is the difference between the use of `subsample` argument of `conv2d` and the application of `max_pool_2d` subsampling after `conv2d`?
   That is what is the difference between:

   ```
   conv2d( ..., subsample=(2,2) )
   ```

   and

   ```
   a = conv2d( ..., subsample = (1,1) )
   max_pool_2d( a, ds = (2,2) )
   ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In answer to your first question, [here is the section of the Theano docs that addresses it](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/nnet/conv.html):

> Two similar implementation exists for conv2d:
>
> ```
> signal.conv2d and nnet.conv2d.
> ```
>
> The former implements a traditional 2D convolution, while the latter
>   implements the convolutional layers present in convolutional neural
>   networks (where filters are 3D and pool over several input channels).

Under the hood they both call the same function, so the only difference is the user interface.

Regarding your second question, the result is different. The equivalent call to:

```
conv2(..., subsample=(2,2))
```

would be:

```
conv2d(...,subsample=(1,1))[:,:,::2,::2]
```

In other words `conv2d` doesn't take the max over the whole pooling region, but rather the element at index `[0,0]` of the pooling region.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer. Regarding the sub sampling of `conv2d`: what's the point in implementing such sub sampling scheme? why not implement linear down sampling (i.e., simple average over (2,2) region)? Have you ever encountered a case where `subsample` argument was different than (1,1)? If so, could you share this example - what is the motivation behind such sampling? Thanks!

Comment: Doing it that way save computation. So if you suppose your filter are a little translation invariant, skipping some computation to speed it up seem interesting. I don't recall having heard someone try/report linear sub sampling. I know that the max pooling operation is frequently used. The idea is that is the pattern appear at one point, you keep it. Otherwise you don't. It help get some translation invariance.

Comment: max_pooling is indeed a very common practice, I was asking about the "zero-holding" subsampling option. But thank you anyway for your good answers!

Comment: I think what theano docs calls subsampling is often referred to as "strides" in CNN literature, if that makes it clearer for someone.

Comment: I'll add this in Theano doc.